# How to allow Google Assistant Action to show information on Chromecast?

Tags: actions-on-google, chromecast, google-assistant-sdk, google-home, google-assist-api

I am trying to develop a Google Assistant Action that could show different items on a Chromecast display depending on the user input. The problem is that I am unable to find any documentation that demonstrates if this is possible or if it can be done at all.

I have looked at the documentation for the local execution SDK for the Google Assistant but didn't see any mention of a Chromecast being a supported device.

Is this possible, and if it is, how can it be done?

Many thanks for all your answers.

Comment: There is no way to get an Action to send data to a Chromecast

Comment: @NickFelker Ok, thanks for replying. I will have to find another way...